# Not able to center text in TextFormField

Tags: flutter

How can i center a text inside the TextFormField

This is my code for the field

```
currentWeight.add(
    SizedBox(
      height: RepetitionsPadding.constHeight,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(RepetitionsPadding.padding),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 50,
          child: TextFormField(
            maxLength: 3,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
            initialValue: reps.currentWeight.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: 'Satoshi',
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
            onChanged: (value) => {reps.currentWeight = value},
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "0",
              counterText: "",
              border: InputBorder.none,
              isCollapsed:
                  true, // Collapse the input field to its intrinsic height
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 0), // Adjust vertical content padding
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

[image: Highligted text field]

Not really sure whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every font has different height, you can manually specify the height of the text span using [height](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html) in TextStyle like the demo below:

[image]

You can change the height value until it looks no gap abobe the text.

Hopefully it can solve your problem, Thanks

Workaround code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: TextFormField(
              maxLength: 3,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
              initialValue: '',
              style: const TextStyle(
                textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontFamily: 'Satoshi',
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                height: 1.2, // <----------- add height
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {},
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: "0",
                counterText: "",
                border: InputBorder.none,
                isCollapsed:
                    true, // Collapse the input field to its intrinsic height
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 0), // Adjust vertical content padding
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please add code instead of sharing image.

Comment: Updated! The code is only to demonstrate the result in the dartpad